# v.surf.idw on grass return : no data points found

Tags: grass-gis

I'm a newbie with grass and I'm using grass (6.4.3) with the GUI... running Ubuntu 13.04 for what it's worth.

Here is my region :

```
projection: 99 (Lambert Conformal Conic)
zone:       0
datum:      ** unknown (default: WGS84) **
ellipsoid:  wgs84
north:      871548
south:      871035
west:       176353
east:       176851
nsres:      1
ewres:      1
rows:       513
cols:       498
cells:      255474
```

Here are the five first lines of the files from which I created a vector map with `v.in.ascii` :

```
871207.125|176633.609375|322.54595947|1
871209.75|176633.84375|323.36795044|2
871207.4375|176623.8125|321.85391235|3
871213.75|176628.359375|322.46286011|4
871207.25|176658.4375|324.73287964|5
```

In table manager I have :

```
cat dbl_1 dbl_2 dbl_3 str_1
integer double precision double precision double precision character
```

I'd like to get a raster from this, so I'm trying to use `v.surf.idw`.

I cannot understand what to put in the column argument of this function.

```
When I put dbl_3, I get :
6423 records selected from table
WARNING : No record for point (cat = 6424)
WARNING : No record for point (cat = 6425)
0 points loaded
ERROR: No data points found
```

When I put double precision it is not working, I've tried every ways I can think of.

Thanks for reading me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ([v.surf.idw](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.surf.idw.html)):

```
v.surf.idw input=your_vector_point output=resulting_raster column=your_field_z (npoints=n power=n)
```

**but you must before fix the region on your vector layer**

```
g.region vect=your_vector_point
```

Otherwise:

```
ERROR: No data points found
```

Comment: You may want to also add the target raster resolution for g.region (res=xx)

Comment: Just to be crystal clear, my field z is : dbl_3. Thank you, the main problem was the : g.region vect=your_vector_point.